# Add a dynamic key to an anonymous List

Tags: list, c#-4.0

How can I add a dynamic key to an anonymous List such as the mydatetime below:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(datepickerval, ukCulture.DateTimeFormat);
        var qid = (from p in db.Vw_INTERACTPEOPLE
                   select p
                   );

        var AvilList = new List<object>();
        var ddate = myDateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3) + "Jul" + myDateTime.Day;
        foreach (var q in qid)
        {
            AvilList.Add(
                new
                {// Availability
                    Name = q.Fullname,
          here  >>> ddate = "Some Test"
                });
```

Comment: Do you want the value of `ddate` to be the name of the property on the anonymous type? If so, why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do,
 because I have a page which builds a slickgrid, javascript creates the columns which are dynamically built 
by the user selecting 2 dates a start and an end - (all dates in between become cols), this all works fine, then in an Ajax call I return to .net 
and I need to build the data by pairing the column name (date) to the data I want so for example the grid 
may have a column 'SunJul1' so i need to create this in.net and pass the data back (via JavaScriptSerializer)
when I hardcode the date all is good, just no idea how to set it up as a variable.

Comment: What is wrong with having a `Dictionary<string, object>` and simply having the "property" names as dictionary keys? Anonymous types aren't designed to build types at runtime.

Comment: didnt think you could do it, but thought there maybe a strange way around it (which I am kind of doing), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adam says above there is no way to do this using Lists, however since the Slickgrid is expecting a Json return, I simply built the string in .net then returned it via the JavaScriptSerializer serializer, then in the code behind simply used eval to de-serialize back into an array.